# 404 after logging in phpmyadmin with Nginx

Tags: 16.04, nginx, phpmyadmin, php7

I just installed LEMP stack but my phpmyadmin is acting weird every time I log in. After login, I always get error 404.

This is the URL after logging in (NOTE the user is now logged in):

```
http://localhost/index.php?token=c47a44d4fefaa8ef326d507c26fe9541&phpMyAdmin=207bvrfpmrj3r50769qpvjc6m2jrr2mq
```

and I get error 404.

When I type localhost/phpmyadmin, it now works normally.

Comment: Check the nginx error logs to see what path it's trying to reach on the server and compare to known paths?

Comment: were is the error logs located for nginx?
I'm not familiar with it only in apache

Comment: This has nothing to do with installing, it's something you get when trying to log in.

Answer (score 14):

This is a : no need to think setup for Ubuntu 16.04 with php7-fpm already installed.

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Then copy paste just before the last } of the file the following block into /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/default

```
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root /usr/share/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        }
        location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root /usr/share/;
        }
    }
```

Save and restart nginx with :

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: please note : you may note be able to login with root user.
Use phpmyadmin user with password to be found in /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf

Comment: NB: Line number 8 in your answer should read: " fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; " - the $ is missing from  document_root. This helped resolve the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks ... it's strange, because I copied from my own config file, and it has the $ indeed. I edited the code to add the $

Comment: The line "fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;" can be adapted according to your php running version ... Visit /var/run to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good way in my opinion, adding a new location section. This will target the location that we choose for the phpMyAdmin interface that we choose